# Ajax response can't access data items

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a ajax call that returns one line of data, but I can't seem to access the data, any ideas.

**AJAX**

```
$.ajax({

    url: '@Url.Action("BanksDetails")',
    data: JSON.stringify({ Id: BankId }),
    dataType: 'JSON',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    async: true,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log('Data' + data[0].BankName);
    },
    error: function (__x, __h, __m) {
        console.log('ajax returned error', __m, __x, __h);
    }
});
```

**RESPONSE**

```
{"Id":1,"BankName":"Bank xxxxxxx","Funding":70.00}
```

The above gives me error:

```
Cannot read property 'BankName' of undefined
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `data` *is* the object, not an array containing the object. So you don't want the `[0]`, just:

```
console.log('Data' + data.BankName);
```

You get the error from `data[0].BankName` because there is no `0` property on `data`, so `data[0]` is `undefined`, and you can't read a property from the value `undefined.`

(If you needed the `[0]`, the response would need to be `[{"Id":1,"BankName":"Bank xxxxxxx","Funding":70.00}]` — note the `[` and `]`. But `{...}` denotes an object.)

Comment: Agghhh I swear I tried that ages ago and it caused an error...worked this time though, thanks.

Comment: @JBoom: We've all been there. :-)